# Referencing to another model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Just finished my "friends" system in Laravel (5.4) for a projet I'm working on. I call them "connections" in my case. Everything is working fine and I'm now trying to clean everything a little bit.

From the very beginning, following tutorials and SO answers, I put every method in my `User` model (which is not *that* bad: a connection is related to a user). But I'd like to clean and put everything related to my connections into a model named `Connection`.

1. Does the `User` model should handle everything related to connections, or my cleaning wish makes sense and a `Connection` model is legit?
2. How to achieve that regarding the code below? How to reference to `User` now I'm not inside the class anymore and `$this` becoming pointless?

#### Connection model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Connection extends Authenticatable
{
    const PENDING = 0;
    const ACCEPTED = 1;
    const REJECTED = 2;
}
```

#### User model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    // Get connections the user initiated by himself
    public function connectionsOfOwner() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'connections', 'user_id', 'connection_id')->withPivot('status');
    }

    // Get connections the user has been invited to
    public function connectionsOf() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'connections', 'connection_id', 'user_id')->withPivot('status');
    }

    // Accessor allowing to call $this->connections
    public function getConnectionsAttribute() {
        if (!array_key_exists('connections', $this->relations)) {
            $this->loadConnections();
        }

        return $this->getRelation('connections');
    }

    // Check if a Laravel relation named "connection" exists
    protected function loadConnections() {
        if (!array_key_exists('connections', $this->relations)) {
            $this->setRelation('connections', $this->mergeConnections());
        }
    }

    // Merge "connectionsOfOwner" and "connectionsOf"
    protected function mergeConnections() {
        return $this->connectionsOfOwner->merge($this->connectionsOf);
    }

    // Get pending connections
    public function getPendingConnections() {
        $filtered = $this->connections->filter(function ($value, $key) {
            if ($value->pivot->status == 0) {
                return $value;
            }
        });

        return $filtered;
    }

    // Get accepted connections
    public function getAcceptedConnections() {
        $filtered = $this->connections->filter(function ($value, $key) {
            if ($value->pivot->status == 1) {
                return $value;
            }
        });

        return $filtered;
    }

    // Add a connection
    public function addConnection($user) {
        $this->connectionsOfOwner()->attach($user->id);
    }

    // Accept a connection
    public function acceptConnection($user) {
        $this->connectionsOf()->syncWithoutDetaching([$user->id => ['status' => Connection::ACCEPTED]]);
        $this->connectionsOfOwner()->attach($user->id, ['status' => Connection::ACCEPTED]);
    }

    // Remove a connection
    public function removeConnection($user) {
        $this->connectionsOfOwner()->detach($user->id);
        $this->connectionsOf()->detach($user->id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could skip the Connection Model and keep that functionality in a trait "HasConnections" that you use in th User model.

Jeffrey Way briefly talks about this approach in Laracon2017: https://streamacon.com/video/laracon-us-2017/day-2-jeffrey-way

Good luck!

Comment: Hum, thanks, but as I understand, traits are more an easy way to copy/paste code among several classes. Not sure that's what I wanted to do. But maybe my question is not an issue and all my `connections` stuffs are welcome in `User` model, as asked on first question?